# Two LIKE concate with Two Limits in sql

Tags: php, mysqli, fetch, sql-like, concatenation

I am fetching data from server like this:

```
    $con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM story  WHERE category LIKE CONCAT('%' ,'WorldList', '%') ORDER BY IDStory DESC limit 20";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
    mysqli_query ($con,"set character_set_results='utf8'");
    while($finalresult=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){}
```

Now I want to get the data of another category like this :

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM story  WHERE category LIKE CONCAT('%' ,'WorldList', '%') ORDER BY IDStory DESC limit 20 AND LIKE CONCAT('%' ,'WorldTop', '%') ORDER BY IDStory DESC limit 1,20";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
    mysqli_query ($conn,"set character_set_results='utf8'");
    while($finalresult=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){}
```

I know that it is wrong this is not a query but how can I make it possible like this.PS: I am new in PHP

Comment: It looks like you need 2 queries, joined by a `UNION` -> `SELECT * FROM story  WHERE category LIKE CONCAT('%' ,'WorldList', '%') ORDER BY IDStory DESC limit 20 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM story  WHERE category LIKE CONCAT('%' ,'WorldTop', '%') ORDER BY IDStory DESC limit 1,20`

Comment: Just paste that query in sql2 ? Cause I don't now about `UNION`

Comment: Yes, you would use that in your `$sql2` -> `$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM .... UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ..."`. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: not working gimme an error!

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: `myqsli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean give ....`

Answer (score 1):

use sql `union`

```
SELECT * FROM story  WHERE category LIKE CONCAT('%' ,'WorldList', '%') limit 20 
UNION
SELECT * FROM story  WHERE category LIKE CONCAT('%' ,'WorldTop', '%') ORDER BY IDStory DESC limit 20
```

Comment: try to execute each queries separately in phpmyadmin or mysql client and check the results

Comment: i checked the same in my local with a different table, and its working fine. pls share table structure

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM story 
      WHERE category LIKE CONCAT('%' ,'WorldList', '%') 
      AND category LIKE CONCAT('%' ,'WorldTop', '%') ORDER BY IDStory DESC limit 20";
```

You cannot use `ORDER BY` or `AND` after `LIMIT`. Alternatively you could use `BOOLEAN MODE`

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM story WHERE MATCH (category) 
     AGAINST ('+WorldList +WorldTop' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY IDStory DESC limit 20";
```

Comment: I need two limits :( like for **WordList** `Limit 20` and for **WorldTop** `Limit 1,20`